# Books about Markov Models

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, markov-process

I am looking about books on Markov chains, with recent findings such as autoregressive HMM, HMM with inputs, multiple HMM connected together.

Is there anything I can look at?

Comment: Have you looked at these? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/resources-for-learning-markov-chain-and-hidden-markov-models

Comment: These may also be helpful: 1) http://www.quora.com/Hidden-Markov-Models/What-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-Hidden-Markov-Models, 2) http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-40264-2